# Windows UI Progress Ring - Unwanted Black Overlay

Tags: windows, xaml, user-interface, uwp

There is a Windows UI Progress Ring that appears during a save dialog, and it has a semi-transparent black box overlay attached to it. I do not want this overlay, I only want the ring.

[This is how it appears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctI64.png)

Here is what creates it - SaveingDialog.xaml. I expunged the solution name and replaced with with [SOLUTION].

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="[SOLUTION].SaveingDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:[SOLUTION]"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="Transparent"
    x:Name="Dialog"
    Width="200"
    MinWidth="200"
    Height="200"
    MinHeight="200"
    BorderThickness="0"
    BorderBrush="Transparent"
    Style="{StaticResource TrimDialog}">

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ProgressRing IsActive="True" Width="200" Height="200" Foreground="#FF404040"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

I can't seem to figure out what causes this behavior. Making the foreground transparent removes the ring but leaves the overlay. Adding a transparent background to the grid or the ProgressRing does nothing. I can't seem find any other documentation or issues like this elsewhere online. There are other ProgressRings in the code that look similar to this but don't have this issue.

Please note I inherited this codebase from a sole developer who is no longer with my company; I remember this was discussed and he could not find a fix.

My question is: Is there anything that's missing from this .xaml, or could the issue come from elsewhere?

Comment: Hi,
Have you try to add a ProgressRing in a Page (ie your main page) for test purpose ?
What are the values of targetSDK and minTargetSDK on your project ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a solution for your issue :
Install the **Microsoft.UI.Xaml** library and replace the following line of your code :

```
<ProgressRing IsActive="True" Width="200" Height="200" Foreground="#FF404040"/>
```

by

```
<muxc:ProgressRing IsActive="True" Foreground="#FF404040" />
```

And ensure to add the corresponding namespace on the root element of your xaml document :

```
xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
```

Microsoft.UI.Xaml is a library developed by Microsoft to easily manage controls of Framework (retrocompatibility, extensions), maybe with the ProgressRing control of this library thats fixs your issue.

My first intuition is an UI issue with contentdialog... but i'm not sure and I've never faced to this issue with ProgressRing of Framework.